# Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 crashes - ieframe.dll

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 is crashing rather randomly, not at any specific time like opening a preview pane or message.  Event viewer gives the following

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.6131.5000, time stamp: 0x509b1020
Faulting module name: ieframe.dll, version: 9.0.8112.16464, time stamp: 0x50ec98f5
```

Similar events have been logged only with `URLMON.DLL`, but with `ieframe.dll` more frequent.  I'm looking where to start with this problem, and I'm starting with running outlook in safe mode using `Outlook /safe` from the start menu.  Further complicating this issue are 2 programs syncing email to other calenders.  Should I start with these additional programs that are syncing email as being possible culprits? Or does this have to do with Internet Explorer because of the DLL associated with these crashes? I've tried `regsvr32` with both DLL's mentioned, with ieframe being unsuccessful. So my question is: what's causing Outlook to crash?

Comment: Things to try: 1) Repair Office. 2) "Uninstall" and reinstall IE from Control Panel / Windows Features.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is rather late, but I've encountered and solved a very similar error, and I think it could be a guide for others with this or similar problems.

[Windows 7 SP1 x64]

In this case it was when I opened a folder in Windows Explorer containing an url link. Putting an url-link on the desktop would even put windows explorer in a crash loop.

Event Log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Event ID:      1000
Level:         Error
Description:
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a144
Faulting module name: ieframe.DLL, version: 8.0.7601.18404, time stamp: 0x530aaee5
Exception code: 0xc0000096
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ad27e
Faulting process id: 0xb70
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\ieframe.DLL
```

When i serached the web for similar problems I found some posts about corrupt files, so I ran a system file integrity check `sfc /scannow`, and it indeed returned that it found errors and tried repairs but failed, however gave no further details as of what files were affected.

The log file that is used by `SFC` is `%windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log`, but is rather big and contain other messages as well. To filter out the relevant results you can run `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log >c:\sfcdetails.txt`

Here I could find the following:

```
Info  CSI  000002ef [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
Info  CSI  000002f1 [SR] Verify complete
Info  CSI  000002f2 [SR] Repairing 1 components
Info  CSI  000002f3 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
Info  CSI  000002f5 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"ieframe.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ieframe, Version = 8.0.7601.18404, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
Info  CSI  000002f7 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"ieframe.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ieframe, Version = 8.0.7601.18404, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
Info  CSI  000002f8 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:156{78}]"Package_5_for_KB2936068~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.2936068-42_neutral_GDR"
Info  CSI  000002fb [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32"\[l:22{11}]"ieframe.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
Info  CSI  000002fd [SR] Repair complete
Info  CSI  000002fe [SR] Committing transaction
```

As I mentioned before, the repair failed, but, note the following line: `This component was referenced by "Package_5_for_KB2936068~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.2936068-42_neutral_GDR"`, this is a Windows Update package! If you check the [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2936068) it lists `ieframe.dll` among the files being updated, and in the log it says `"source file in store is also corrupted"`. This means the update package is corrupted, and source of the corrupted system file!

I uninstalled this update and rebooted, and the problem went away! SFC does reports no problem either.

I have as of yet not tried to re-install this update, but I emptied the Windows Update download cache `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`, so it won't install the corrupt files again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'd say this is a problem with outlook trying to render HTML content in a window somewhere.  Perhaps the DLL is corrupt, out of date, or somehow not linked properly.

Here's some advice on generically resolving ieframe.dll errors:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/ieframedll.htm

A repair install of Outlook or IE might resolve the problem, or you have a plugin for Outlook that is calling the DLL incorrectly.